Can weapon special abilities be activated at the same time with a single command?
For example, both frost and flaming special abilities can only be activated "upon command", and such a command word usually takes a standard action.
If someone gets a frost flaming +1 longsword, does this mean he has to take 2 standard actions (1 for frost and 1 for flaming) before he can make both abilities become active? Or can all special abilities be triggered together upon the same command as a single standard action?
How does accidental activation of a command word work?
I have seen this question, but it doesn't explain the case when a single item has multiple different abilities.

According to the FAQ it depends on the individual weapon
The rules are unclear regarding this special case but the FAQ has an entry that exactly adresses it. The entry is quite long, here are only the crucial parts:

Activating an energy power requires a standard action, but once you
activate energy power, the power works until you use another action to
deactivate it.
(...)
The energy from a flaming, frost, shock, flaming burst, icy burst, or
shocking burst weapon never harms you while you’re wielding or
carrying the activated weapon (see the power descriptions), and it
will not harm your equipment. If you lose or set down an activated
weapon, the energy it produces will harm other objects it touches, so
it is best to deactivate it first. There’s nothing illogical about a
flaming, frost, shock weapon (at least not within any framework that
allows weapons to generate energy in the first place), and there’s no
rule against such weapons (think of the weapon as having fiery,
frosty, shocking flames). The character creating such a weapon
decides how it can be activated. Most such weapons probably are made
so that the wielders can activate all three powers simultaneously, or
activate them one at a time, as desired.



The fire does not harm the wielder. The effect remains until another command is given. A flaming weapon deals an extra 1d6 points of fire damage on a successful hit.

(Flaming special weapon ability description)

The cold does not harm the wielder. The effect remains until another command is given. A frost weapon deals an extra 1d6 points of cold damage on a successful hit.

(Frost special weapon ability description)

The electricity does not harm the wielder. The effect remains until another command is given. A shock weapon deals an extra 1d6 points of electricity damage on a successful hit.

(Shock special weapon ability description)
In all three cases, we have a statement that the effect does not harm the wielder (and, implicitly, their stuff), that the effect lasts as long as you want it to, and that the only thing it actually does do, is impart energy damage “on a successful hit.”
As such, there is absolutely no reason to have to activate these weapons—their effect lasts indefinitely and there is no reason to turn it off. So if you draw a +1 flaming frost shock longsword from a scabbard, it’s already on fire, magically ice-cold, and wreathed in crackling electricity. Because it already was so, in your scabbard. Because you didn’t turn it off last time. Because there was no reason to do so.
That doesn’t actually answer your question, it just provides motivation for not needing the answer. The true answer is... problematic. RAW, well,

Command word activation means that a character speaks the word and the item activates. […] Activating a command word magic item is a standard action

(Command word magic item activation description)
Strictly speaking, the rule specifying that activating a command-word magic item takes a standard action says that the item activates with a command word. That is, one command word, one standard action, activate the entire item. Flaming, frost, and shock, all in one go. Which is reasonable, in the case of a magical weapon. Not at all reasonable, in the case of command-word items that allow you to cast spells. Casting multiple spells simultaneously is immensely powerful—note Quicken Spell’s +4 spell level cost, and that this is significantly better than that—and the magic item pricing guidelines don’t account for it at all. (There is technically the 50% extra surcharge for combining separate magical effects, but that surcharge applies—at least per the guidelines—in all cases, not just command-word multi-activation cases, and in any event 50% is still far less than Quicken Spell costs, while actually being better.)
We could start playing the game of saying “OK, RAW ignoring that bit of RAW,” but that’s nonsense. It becomes purely a game of “OK, what exactly are you ignoring and how are you papering over the gap, with what exact wording?” and at that point you should just be making a ruling.
We could look to secondary rules sources, too, such as the FAQ, which Peregrin’s answer helpfully quotes. The problem is, the FAQ is often wrong, which makes it a poor source. In particular, this entry suggests that, if left on, one of these weapons will damage its surroundings if left unattended. That doesn’t preclude our sheathing it (that’s still considered attended by the game rules so long as we wear or hold the scabbard), but we better not put it down while sheathed—or onto anything fragile. And all of this is the FAQ reading between the lines and deciding “well it doesn’t say that they don’t do this,” which is not an appropriate role for the FAQ to take—especially without mentioning that this is what they’re doing. The actual rules only indicate that these weapons damage anything by successfully hitting that thing. Taking the statement that it doesn’t harm the wielder and understanding that as implicitly saying it does harm other things is inappropriate for the FAQ, and not borne out by subsequent errata and reprintings of the Dungeon Master’s Guide, which have not added anything about that to the official rules.
Anyway, assuming we look past that, there are some other things about the FAQ entry that might be helpful, if we were in a mood to consider it at all. It confirms that not harming the wielder includes not harming the wielder’s equipment. It confirms that “until another command is given” refers to a separate word specifically for turning it off—and not, as suggested in comments, to just any subsequent command word, making it impossible to activate sequentially. And it confirms that all three properties can be created such that a single command word turns them all on: fine. Ish. Just don’t go applying that to other command-word items.
But that is the correct ruling, that you can activate and deactivate these kinds of special weapon abilities all at once. There’s vanishingly little reason to ever do so, but if you ever want to (dramatic effect, I suppose), you should be able to actually do it (dramatically, that is, rather than dragged out across three rounds). There aren’t really rules to directly support that, but as established, we need something that isn’t the rules. On this, that’s really straightforward and I can think of no reason anyone should even consider ruling any other way, nor have I ever seen anyone do so. Everyone just allows them to activate/deactivate together without thinking about it because they just assume that’s how it works, because that’s how it should work. It doesn’t, but we shouldn’t let that stop us.

I believe that the phrase 'until another command is given' precludes activating them serially. It does not say 'until a command to turn it off is given', and so if the words were different from each other, using the command for a second ability while the first is active would disable the first. Having all the abilities on the same word does seem to cause all to activate simultaneously, indeed it seems to enforce it, preventing the activation of the abilities individually.

@Chemus I read that as “there is a specific word for ‘on,’ and another, different word for ‘off.’” Having any subsequent command word turn it off is just untenable if you start following it to its logical conclusions, and is a problematic enough ruling that I would not play under a DM who thought it was appropriate to implement.

@Chemus As (briefly) addressed in my answer, the FAQ confirms my reading (...for whatever little the FAQ is worth).

DMG 303: "Characters exposed to burning oil, bonfires, and noninstantaneous
magic fires such as a wall of fire might find their clothes,
hair, or equipment on fire." An activated flaming weapon which is "sheathed in
fire" is a source of noninstantaneous magic fire. Therefore it's logical to assume that it can ignite stuff and should better be deactivated before left unattended. I'd say the FAQ is in line with the rules.

@Peregrin 1. That only covers fire, not cold or electricity, which have no such general rule. 2. That rule specifies that characters exposed to these things might catch fire; unattended objects are not considered, while those are precisely what the FAQ claims would be affected. 3. That rule kind of skips over the crucial step of determining who is subject to this “risk” and when, which we see borne out by things like wall of fire spelling it out for their particular case. That rule alone doesn’t indicate that flaming would do this, and flaming itself certainly doesn’t.

Do you really think unattended objects can't catch fire while a character's hair/clothes etc can? I mean, of course, no player or DM really wants to be concerned all the time with combustible materials becoming accidentally ignited. That's probably the reason why the rules are so vague. I think one should not really bother about them. On the other hand — I'd say there is no doubt that you will set a haystack on fire, when you put your flaming sword inside...

@Peregrin My concern with that comment was near-purely with the FAQ exceeding its mandate without warning users that this is what it was doing. I will always object to that, because I think it’s a terrible practice and one that causes considerable harm to players’ shared understanding of the game and communication about it. I agree that it’s the sort of thing that sometimes makes sense and other times isn’t worth the brainpower, and that’s an awkward thing for the rules, though frankly I wish the rules would just admit that instead of pretending they’ll cover everything.

@KRyan I'd agree that it was clearly solely intended that it was for turning it off if it said 'until commanded otherwise' or '... the command to turn it off'. 'Another command' is synonymous with 'Any other command". Having acidic, flaming, frost and shock simultaneously active is up to each DM, IMO, and indeed I don't see it as the default for how magic items [historically] had been presented. [prior to 3e, only flaming was core... partly as an example for DMs to base other things on]

@Chemus Well, all I can say is that I disagree with your reading of the text, strongly disagree with your reading of the situation with respect to how the game plays, and can point to a ton of evidence that in 3.x at least, they’re all meant to go together and whatever prior editions did is sort of irrelevant because magic items are an aspect of the game that 3.x handled very differently from those before (and those after, for that matter).

One thing to be aware of is that sometimes people do want to disable part of their weapon abilities. For example, a flesh golem can be healed by magical electricity attack, and a fighter may want to disable electricity damage from his sword but still keeping his fire and cold damage operating. (By the reading, magical weapon's special ability should still be counted as "magical attack" since it is powered by magic.)

@TerryWindwalker Very questionable whether a shock weapon qualifies as a magical attack, but I’ll stipulate that there may be very rare reasons to do so.
